# "NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA" on jasmine TestBed causing to run full test suite despite 'fdescribe"

Tags: javascript, karma-jasmine

When I include `schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]` in jasmine testBed, I get all tests in my suite to run despite having written `fdescribe` to that specific component. I have other tests running with it but none has shown this behavior. Does anyone know how to solve or debug it?